# CSS for one column, two rows with siblings with flexbox (like the flag of Benin!)

Tags: css, flexbox

This simplest way I've found to explain this is simply to show you the flag of Benin:

[image]

I'd like to do something similar with flexbox in CSS, but so far I’ve been flummoxed.

The key is that I need each of the three regions to be siblings, something like:

```html
<div class=flag>
  <div class=green></div>
  <div class=yellow></div>
  <div class=red></div>
</div>
```

```css
.flag { 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

/* below this I'm not sure */
.green { 

}

.red, .yellow { 

}
```

Is this possible without adding an intermediary node to contain `.red` and `.yellow`? It's easy at that point, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do what I describe above.

Comment: See if this helps you: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Stupid question, but are you trying to get the hang of flexboxes or are you trying to draw the flag of Benin?

Comment: Trying to learn about Flexbox. My drawing skills are not immense but I think even I could pull off this work of art :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You can use wrapping columns to get your Benin Flag:**

The first (left) column is .green at `height:100%` relative to the .flag container.

The second (right) column is .yellow,.red at `height:50%` relative to .flag

And the .green is allocated `width:40%` relative to .flag

*Good luck with your project!*

[image]

```css
.flag{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column wrap;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.green{background:green;}
.yellow{background:yellow;}
.red{background:red;}

.col1{width:40%;height:100%;}
.col2{width:60%;height:50%;}
```

```html
<div class=flag>
  <div class='col1 green'></div>
  <div class='col2 yellow'></div>
  <div class='col2 red'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow I had come under the delusion that `display:flex` containers only had an effect if they were parents of children with one of the `flex-*` rules set. But I see from your example that `display:flex` also affects the way that child elements behave with respect to each other, as long as they have set dimensions of some kind.

Thanks!

Comment: No flexbox guide I could find on the whole internet explains this simple layout, awesome!

Comment: This is great. Does anyone know how to create this exact layout without setting the parent's height?

Comment: Plus one to the question of doing this without fixed height :)